# Find shortest path from adj_matrix in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shortest-path

I am new to Ruby and I am trying to find the shortest path from an origin node to a destination node given a adj_matrix which is a 2D array.

Assumptions: Ignore direct path possibility

My code works currently with the following description/logic i have.

However, if i change to another adj_matrix to test for other test cases, it will not return me the optimal path.

Is there other better way to do?

[image]

def find_way(adj_matrix, origin, dest)
    result = [origin]

```
destPath = checkDestinationPath(adj_matrix,origin) #[1,2,3,4]
originPath = checkOriginPath(adj_matrix,dest) #[6,7,9]

value = nil
distance = 0
for i in 0..originPath.length-1 
    element = originPath[i] #6,7,9

    path = checkOriginPath(adj_matrix,element) #find which vertex go the element Eg:6-[1,4,7,8,9]  7-[1,6,8]  9-[4,5,6,8]
    allVertexInElement = checkFound(destPath,path) #stores common vertex that are also in destPath (Eg: 4)

    if allVertexInElement.length != 0 
        for j in 0..allVertexInElement.length-1
            currVertex = allVertexInElement[j] #4
            a = checkDestinationPath(adj_matrix,currVertex) 
            distance = adj_matrix[origin][currVertex] #8
            if currVertex == dest  #exit entire for loop
                distance = adj_matrix[origin][currVertex] + adj_matrix[currVertex][dest] 
                value = "#{currVertex}"  + "," + "#{element}" 
                break
            else 
             commonVertex = checkFound2(originPath,a)  # 6,9    
                for k in 0..commonVertex.length-1  #2 or more possible path: 0-4-6-8 vs 0-4-9-8
                    current = commonVertex[k] #6,9
                    distance += adj_matrix[currVertex][current]
                    distance += adj_matrix[current][dest] 

                    if k == 0
                        shortestDist = distance #20
                         value = "#{currVertex}"  + "," + "#{element}"  # 4,6                            
                    else
                        if distance < shortestDist
                            shortestDist = distance #16  
                            value = "#{currVertex}"  + "," + "#{element}"  #4,9

                        end
                    end
                    distance = adj_matrix[origin][currVertex] #reset: 8
                end         
            end   
        end
    end
end

values = value.split(",")
values.each do |x|
    result << x.to_i #4,9
 end

result << dest #8
return result #[0,4,9,8]
```

end

Comment: Enumerating all paths from origin to destination ("brute force") is a highly-inefficient way to find a shortest path. Consider implementing a standard shortest path algorithm, such as [Dijkstra's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm).

Comment: Do I have to first convert my adj_matrix to a graph first?